# Trigonometric functions equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can someone help me to solve this?

> $$
> \sin\Bigl(x+\frac\pi4\Bigr) \cos\Bigl(x+\frac\pi4\Bigr) + \frac{\sqrt3}2\sin(2x) = 2\cos^2x 
> $$

I tried like this:
\begin{align}
\frac12 \sin\Bigl(2x+\frac\pi2\Bigr) + \frac{\sqrt3}2 \sin(2x) &= 2\cos^2x \\[4pt]
\frac12\cos(2x) + \frac{\sqrt3}2 \sin(2x) &= 2\cos^2x
\end{align}

I just noticed my mistake in multiplying $\frac\pi4$ by $2$.

Comment: hint: combine the terms with $\frac{\pi}4$, then use lines of $\frac{\pi}3$ and addition formula.

Comment: First step: what have you tried?

Comment: Please include Your attempt to let us understand where exactly you are stuck, Help me questions without any context or attempt are like a Magnet to attract downvotes

Comment: I added my attempt but I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

You are closer than you think.

As pointed out in the other answer
$$2\cos^2(x) = 1+\cos(2x)$$
Putting this in your last line
$$\frac12\cos(2x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(2x) = 1 + \cos(2x)$$
Reoganize
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(2x) - \frac12\cos(2x) = 1$$
Then, notice that
$$\cos \frac\pi6 = \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \text{ and }\sin\frac\pi6 = \frac12$$
The equation becomes
$$\cos\frac\pi6\sin(2x) - \sin\frac\pi6\cos(2x) = 1$$
Using the identity for $\sin(A-B)$
$$\sin\left(2x-\frac\pi6\right) = 1$$
$$2x-\frac\pi6 = \frac\pi2 + 2k\pi$$
$$x = \frac\pi3 + k\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

Use known trigonometric identities. For example,
$$\sin(x + \pi/2)\cos(x +\pi/2) = \sin(2x + \pi)/2 = -\sin(2x)/2.$$
Another useful one is $2\cos^2x = 1 + \cos(2x)$. Can you solve it starting here?

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt3-1}2\sin(2x)=1+\cos(2x)$

Comment: OK, not write $\sin(2x)$ in terms of $\cos(2x)$, and pay attention to signs and division by $0$...

Comment: $\sin(2x)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(2x)}$ but I think this is not a good solution

Comment: And now use $(1-\cos(2x))(1+\cos(2x)) = (1 - \cos^2(2x))$. :D Keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sin\Bigl(x+\frac\pi4\Bigr) \cos\Bigl(x+\frac\pi4\Bigr) + \frac{\sqrt3}2\sin(2x) = 2\cos^2x 
$$

$$
\sin\Bigl(x+\frac\pi4\Bigr) \cos\Bigl(x+\frac\pi4\Bigr) + \frac{\sqrt3}2\sin(2x) - 2\cos^2x =0
$$

$$2\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4})+\sqrt{3}\sin (2x)-4\cos^2 (x)=0$$

$$2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}\cos (x)-\sqrt{2} \sin (x)}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2}\cos (x)-\sqrt{2} \sin (x)}{2}+\sqrt{3} \sin(2x)-4\cos^2 (x)=0$$

$$(\cos(x)-\sin(x))(\sin(x)+\cos(x))+\sqrt{3} \sin(2x)-4\cos^2 (x)=0$$

$$\sqrt{3} \sin(2x)-\sin^2 (x)-3\cos^2 (x)=0$$

$$\sqrt{3} \sin(2x)-2-\cos(2x)=0$$

$$-2(\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(2x))-2=0$$

$$-2\sin(-2x+\frac{\pi}{6})=0$$

Now you can proceed from here.